# Switch wiring method

Tags: switches, wiring

How should I wire this type of switch? Is there a specific connector I should use to connect the wires to the switch, or can I simply ignore the screws and solder the wires directly to the switch's holes?

[image]

Comment: I believe this one is designed to use a cable lug or possibly get crimped with the naked wire. It's not meant for soldering or that would be a different kind of switch, likely also available from the same manufacturer. You probably _can_ solder just fine, it will be conducting tin, but why not order the correct switch instead?

Answer (score 1):

M3 cable lugs may be used.

[image]

The cable may be crimped or soldered.